# Tableview crashes when reloading data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I've unexpected problems with tableviews. It seems that the app quits without a error every time I try to reload my tableviews' data. I know that the array is formed correctly, so there's something wrong with these functions:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if tableView.tag == 1 {

            return latest.count
        }
        else if tableView.tag == 2{
            return older.count
        }
        else {

            return 0 //In case of error
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell:UITableViewCell?

        if tableView.tag == 1 {
            print("Success")
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "latestCell")! as UITableViewCell

            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle,
                                   reuseIdentifier: "latestCell")

            cell?.textLabel?.text = latest[indexPath.row]

            cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = latestSub[indexPath.row]

            cell?.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator

            return cell!

        }

        else if tableView.tag == 2 {

            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "olderCell")! as UITableViewCell

            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle,
                                   reuseIdentifier: "olderCell")


            cell?.textLabel?.text = older[indexPath.row]

            cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = olderSub[indexPath.row]

            cell?.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator

            return cell!
        }

        else {
            return cell!
        }
    }
```

The answers before to these type of questions here were about forgetting to set delegates and datasource and so... So I believe this is an appropriate question.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
var latest = [String]()

var older = [String]()

var latestSub = [String]()

var olderSub = [String]()


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    latestTable.reloadData()
    olderTable.reloadData()
}
```

The full log;

2017-02-16 15:57:28.889 NotebookApp[24985:604704] Firebase automatic screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2017-02-16 15:57:28.997 NotebookApp[24985:]  Firebase Analytics v.3600000 started
2017-02-16 15:57:28.999 NotebookApp[24985:]  To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
2017-02-16 15:57:29.012:  FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2017-02-16 15:57:29.020 NotebookApp[24985:]  Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2017-02-16 15:57:29.090 NotebookApp[24985:]  The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function properly. 
2017-02-16 15:57:29.180 NotebookApp[24985:]  Firebase Analytics enabled
2017-02-16 15:57:45.703779 NotebookApp[24985:604704] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2017-02-16 16:01:34.316879 NotebookApp[24985:604704] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/tuomasnummela/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AA87179A-11E5-4A3A-A63F-B785AA71EC95/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-02-16 16:01:34.317476 NotebookApp[24985:604704] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.

I kind of didn't think that there would be anything useful here because when the app quits it doesn't take me to the error-page-thing and highlight any code.

[What my project looks like after the app has forcedly closed itself.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2bOE.jpg)

Comment: Share your array value and method in which you are reload the table.

Comment: I also append those arrays in another function so if that seems to be the problem I can post that too. But it includes firebase so that'll go on forever.

Comment: So your app is crashed as soon as you load the viewcontroller, right?

Comment: @user7356029 What is the error in error log?

Comment: Have you setted numberOfSections?

Comment: Print count of array before returning cell count

Comment: If there is a crash, show the error log.

Comment: The app crashes when the view loads, yes. The error log:

Comment: Is in the main question, I mean.

Comment: Where did everyone go? :( :D

Comment: @user7356029, you need to provide crash log. or may be stack trace

Comment: The log I just added in the main post is ALL I get. The app doesn't crash the same way it usually does. It doesn't show anything in the debug-area, the app just closes itself and nothing happens in the Xcode-Project.

Comment: Why so many down votes?

Comment: Thank you all so much for trying to figure this out. It works well now, so problem solved. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things that can go wrong here is it can't find the cell with the reuse identifier that you are passing in the below line

`cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "olderCell")! as UITableViewCell`

All you have to do is register the cell with reuse identifier in your viewDidLoad

`<olderTableView>.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "olderCell")
<latestTableView>.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "latestCell")`

or

you can simply replace the dequeue and initialization lines with the following

```
if tableView.tag == 1 {
        let reuseId = "latestCell" 
        let latestCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseId) ?? UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)

        latestCell.textLabel?.text = latest[indexPath.row]
        latestCell.detailTextLabel?.text = latestSub[indexPath.row]
        latestCell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator

        return latestCell

    }
```

Comment: @user7356029 i have edited the answer check the second case which should work

Comment: Exactly. The second case you posted worked just like charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, this works well now, but the subtitles on the cells aren't showing. Any idea what that might be about?

Comment: @user7356029 You can try replacing guard with return lines with `let reuseId = "latestCell"
        let latestCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseId) ?? UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)`

Comment: @user7356029 I have edited the answer. If that doesn't work then there should be some issues with your latestSub array like it contains empty strings

Answer (score 0):

The first error is in the `viewDidAppear` you must call the `super.viewDidAppear(animated)`, the tableview reload will never fired.

Comment: This didn't seem to make a difference, is there a second error?

Comment: Missing other informations, the log you are posted is only for Layout.

Comment: The full log is now in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of errors in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`.  The crash is likely from force unwrapping `cell` which was nil in the last line.

Here is my stab at cleaning it up.  Be sure to register you `UITableViewCell` subclass with `tableView.register(SubtitleCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"latestCell")`.  Unless there is other code not visible, you can use the same identifier for `latestCell` and `olderCell` - they don't seem to be different from the code you've posted

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell //can't be optional

    if tableView.tag == 1 {
        print("Success")
       cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "latestCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SubtitleCell
       //cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "latestCell") //don't call this here, make a subclass of UITableViewCell to set style

        cell.textLabel?.text = latest[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = latestSub[indexPath.row]
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        return cell
    }

    else if tableView.tag == 2 {
        //same comments as above
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "olderCell", for: indexPath) as! SubtitleCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = older[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = olderSub[indexPath.row]
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        return cell
    }

    else {
        cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "latestCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell //you were returning nil here - need to return a cell
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how to init the correct cell style

```
class SubtitleCell: UITableViewCell {
   override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}
```

Comment: Crash can't be from the last line since the code has number of rows 0 in the else block so it will never reach the returning nil case in cellForRowAtIndexPath